# How to check the collision by dividing the rectangle diagonally from unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, collision-detection

I try to determine if there is a mouse in the east, west, south, and north directions around the character.

[image]

[image]

I want to determine if the mouse is in the zone of each color.

How do I write code?

Comment: You need to update your question with where you consider to be the "colored section". Also add what code you have tried. You have to try something.

Comment: Clue: `Vector2.Angle()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should considerate the middle of your rectangle as center (0,0) , and the 4 other points of rectangle must have a coordinates like (width/2; hight/2) for right-superior point, (-widht/2;hight/2) for left-superior point etc. 
After that, you can use this code

```
float sign (fPoint p1, fPoint p2, fPoint p3){
    return (p1.x - p3.x) * (p2.y - p3.y) - (p2.x - p3.x) * (p1.y - p3.y);} 

bool PointInTriangle (fPoint mousePos, fPoint v1, fPoint v2, fPointev3) { 
    bool b1, b2, b3;
    b1 = sign(mousePos, v1, v2) < 0.0f;
    b2 = sign(mousePos, v2, v3) < 0.0f;
    b3 = sign(mousePos, v3, v1) < 0.0f;
    return ((b1 == b2) && (b2 == b3));}
```